# Why are my radio buttons showing up as text forms?

Tags: html, radio-button

Here is the code for my radio buttons and I have attached a photo of what they show up as.

I am very clearly a novice at this. Please keep that in mind when responding. I am just learning HTML.

<   BR><   input type="submit" value="Give advice">

<   BR>

<   input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Yes">Yes
<   input type="radio" name="radio1" value="No">No
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSS5u.png)

Comment: Have you tried making a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net) to share a working example here?

Comment: That's so strange, the jsfiddle shows up exactly how I want it but on my webpage it shows up like in the attachment.

Comment: In the browser, try viewing the page source or inspecting the input elements on your web page. I suspect the code on your web page is different than what is shared here.

Comment: So I did the inspect thing and it is a little bit different but only because there are page breaks in there, so it looks like this:

< BR>
< input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Yes">Yes
<BR>
< input type="radio" name="radio1" value="No">No
<BR>

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the blank space between '<' and 'input'.

Comment: So in my actual code that space isn't there, I just put it in there so the HTML would show up on my post. Every time I tried to post this question without that space the HTML would disappear and it would only show "Yes" and "No"